# Return the text as I type in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the data of a text field as I type something in that text field without using any JavaScript library? Something like that is achieved in AngularJS like this:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<hr>
<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

Comment: bind keyup event and inside that event handler update the dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any frameworks/libraries in the sense, you must bind `keyup` event to the `input` element and in the `event` handler you must update the DOM.

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    document.querySelector("h1 strong").textContent= this.value;
});
```

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here" value="">
<hr>
<h1>Hello <strong></strong></h1>
```

Answer (score -6):

Another way of doing it is to use javascript's oninput.

```
 <input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
 }
 </script>
```

[Here is the working example from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_oninput)

Comment: I can place any links I think are useful. You don't tell people what links they need to use.

Comment: Perhaps I worded that too strongly. It's a general sentiment among the SO community that w3schools isn't the best resource. I hate to spew platitudes, but [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com). You are indeed free to link to whichever source you choose, but consider linking to more powerful/reliable resources, like the [mdn](http://developer.mozilla.org) or the [web platform docs](http://www.webplatform.org/), in the future.

Comment: w3schools is not a reliable source, as shown in this example. Using inline event handlers is considered poor practice, as is setting `innerHTML`, which opens your app to all kinds of script injection attacks.

Comment: do you have interest in a moderators opinion? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com/280484#280484